# BackboneJS: How to call function outside view from view's events hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

As an example, here's what I'm looking to do...

```
function doSomething(customParameter) {
    console.log(customParameter);
}

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Other view stuff, skipping it...
    events: {
        'click .someClass': doSomething(customParameter)
    }
});
```

The motivation here is I want to be able to pass variables (local to the view) to some other function outside the view. The reason I want to do this is so that the "other function" is only written once and not four times...it would seriously save my project over 100 lines of code.

After much googling I haven't found a solution to this...any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
function doSomething(customParameter) {
    console.log(customParameter);
}

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Other view stuff, skipping it...
    events: {
        'click .someClass': function(ev) { doSomething(this.customParameter); }
    }
});
```

In this example, you declare a function that passes the arguments needed from the local view to that `doSomething` method.

---

Another way could be to call the doSomething() with the context of the current view, if you don't want to pass all the required arguments:

```
function doSomething(ev) {
    console.log(this.customParameter); // here, the context this will be the view.
}

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Other view stuff, skipping it...
    events: {
        'click .someClass': function(ev) { doSomething.call(this, ev); }
    }
});
```

---

A more OOP approach would be to have a base View for that common code:

```
var MyBaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    doSomething: function(ev) {
        console.log(this.customParameter);
    }
});

var MyView = MyBaseView.extend({
    extends: {
        'click .someClass': 'doSomething'
    }
});
```

---

Probably there are more ways of doing it, you just have to see which scenario applies best to your needs.

Comment: Wow, why did I never think of extending one of my own views before? My code could have been a lot cleaner. @PlanetLotus, the last option might be the best for you.

Comment: Haha I also never thought of extending one of my views in Backbone code. Thanks a ton, I'll give the last two options a shot and see which works best for me!

Comment: The last option is working very well so far. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You can try calling a method that is internal to the view which calls the method in question

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Other view stuff, skipping it...
    events: {
        'click .someClass': 'callSomething'
    },
    callSomething: function() {
        doSomething(customParameter);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm doing this currently. The problem is that the callSomething function is repeated throughout several views. It works, but it's a huge waste of code. I'd like to pull this out into a function outside the view so that it can be called anywhere. Write once, run everywhere, as they say :) the only difference is in the view's variables.